# Set maxlength to Animate CC HTML5 canvas input text component

Tags: maxlength

I work in Animate CC and I only need 2 things. Limit the amount of caracters in a input text component (`maxlength = 15`). Then, add a second input text component and force the user to only enter numbers (`maxlength = 2`).

The pictures shows my windows and the option I got. How can I achieve this? I've learned HTML5 in Animate by myself coming from working in AS2 before. So I would need the answer to be detailed for a beginner like me.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In terms of limiting the amount of characters in the input field you could add something like this to the html output that Animate CC produces when you publish:

```
document.getElementById("test").maxLength = "15";
```

Where your input field is given the name test in the properties panel.

To answer your other question, I don't think you can control what the user can type into an input field, only validate that input afterwards.  I think you would need to use JavaScript (maybe trapping a keyup event) to work this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes you can specify what characters the user can use. 
In the example below the component's name is input1 and we allow only digits

********************* ALLOW ONLY NUMBERS IN INPUT  ******************

```
if (!this.myInput_change_cbk) {
   function myInput_change(evt) {
       // change value here
       console.log(evt.target.value);
       var regex = /[^0-9]/g;
       evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(regex, "");
       // End your custom code
        evt.target.maxlength = 2;
    }
$("#dom_overlay_container").on("keyup", "#input1", myInput_change.bind(this));
this.myInput_change_cbk = true;
```

}